# Get percentages of all unique values for all columns

Tags: mysql

I have a large table with about 40k rows and 240 columns. Some of the columns are true/false as the only possible values. Others have multiple possible strings. What I need to generate is basically an aggregate report that would show all the possible values for each column and the percentage of total rows that have that value (e.g., what percent of all the rows in column 5 are "up", what percent are "down", what percent are "left", etc.)

All I can get to is finding the counts for distinct values in one single column:

`SELECT direction, COUNT(*) as count from full_db3 group by direction order by count desc`

This gives me the total number of rows:

`Select COUNT(*) as count from full_db3`

I don't know how to combine these to give me percents instead of counts. This also only gives me the result for a single column and I'm looking for a way to loop through every column and get the results.

Comment: 240 columns??  I'm sorry for you. It can be done though but the work to do it will be terrible. What you are looking for is called Pivoting table look at it.

Comment: You could always apply this concept: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/447ed/2 - a little unsure on how resource hungry it is and how it would perform on a table with your size.

Comment: Thanks. This would work for a single column and assumes I know the values in the column, which I won't always know (e.g., there may be 50 unique values). It won't work to go through all columns though.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your question is daunting is due to the fact that you have 240 columns. If this is a one time report Excel or Tablaeu may be a good option for creating a quick pivot table with basic statistics.

If you need to do this in MySQL you will need to return the count of each distinct value in each column you care about. Take a column named 'COLUMN1' with possible values, 0,1, and 2.

```
select 
  COLUMN1
  , ROUND( //Round to help control the output
            (count(COLUMN1)* 100 / (select count(*) from TABLE)
          ), 2)
      as Percentage
    from TABLE;
```

This will give you the percentage of each value in the column. Since each of your 240 columns has a different count of distinct values, do not try and merge all of the different percentage charts together. Hopefully this helps get you started in the right direction.